# Fastest method to detect if there is a tag with attribute [itemtype='http://schema.org/Offer']

Tags: javascript

I am looking to detect with Javascript the fastest possible way, if there is a HTML tag with attribute `[itemtype='http://schema.org/Offer']` in the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(document.querySelectorAll("*[itemtype='http://schema.org/Offer']").length){
    alert("It is there!");
}
```

Use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) for [IE 7 and below](http://caniuse.com/queryselector). It is the same CSS selector engine for jQuery, but without all those fancy stuff.

```
document.querySelectorAll = document.querySelectorAll || Sizzle;
```

Comment: @JonathanSampson - Oh yeah. Changed.

Comment: Note that IE only supports this method in Versions 8+

Comment: Do you know a polyfill for not-supported browsers? http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: The client wants IE7 support, and Firefox 3.

Comment: @Pentium10 - You can use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is the CSS selector engine for jQuery

Comment: @Derek haha wow, we must have had the same idea at almost the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Heres some relevant information regarding jQuery [selector speeds](http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19). Obviously it looks like using an ID in your selector would be the fastest, but if you cant do that, limiting the scope to a specific group of tags would also help

..edit..
if all you need to do is select the elements, you can just use the [sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Home) engine. Its what jquery uses internally, and you wont have to worry about any jQuery bloat.

Comment: can't limit to tags, it could be on anything. Also loading jQuery is time consuming.